# Changing Backbone Model defaults attribute

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone View. I want that on some click event, i am able to change the defaults attribute of model.

Comment: want to modify the model attributes on button click?

Answer (score 0):

Inside view initialize use `.on` function ([here is doc](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on)). For example:

```
  initialize: function(options) {
    model.off();  // if you forget to write the line, it works  how many time you rendered this view
    model.on( 'all', this._handleChanges, this); // all or another event  name
  }
```

**Edit**

I used `.off()` beacuse here i wrote all inside `on`. i do  `off` event whitch one  i bind with `on`. [For more inf](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-off)

Comment: it is very brave to remove all events from a model, might brake other parts of the application

Comment: If you use [`this.listenTo(this.model, ...)`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) and [`stopListening`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-stopListening) you usually have fewer problems with interfering with someone else's event handling.